# Show a form without freezing

Tags: c#

I want to show a form but it's freezing, I already do background worker but it also doesn't work.

(I recreate my problem inside the method just need to full load the form)

```
public void show()
{
    Boolean test = false;
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += delegate (object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        while (!test)
        {
            try
            {
                Register dashboardServer = new Register();
                dashboardServer.Show();
                test = true;
            }
            catch (Exception eee)
            {

            }
        }
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: UI needs to run in the main thread. So whatever you do it it should be always the other way round. Do UI in the mainthread and do you actual work in a background thread.

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, use async/await.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is multithreading on Winforms. Here is a helpful link for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/multithreading-in-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8. Please, bear in mind that this is the target to .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: I already added backgrounsd worker but isn't working

Answer (score -1):

BackgroundWorker is kind of obsolet.

You should take a look at [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) to run something asynchronous.

Comment: Microsoft example is bad i don't really understand it. Do an example to me with the while and show a show on it